# Load dicom files

Tags: dicom, xtk

I am trying to view (uncompressed) dicom files using XTK. However the browser does not show anything, although it seems that it is loading normally.

Does it matter that the slices from DICOM files are horizontal? In the Lesson 15 at https://github.com/xtk/X#readme the slices are vertical. The dicom files come from http://www.osirix-viewer.com/datasets/ (BRAINX dataset).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A recent error was found in the DICOM parser, which made slices not be rendered at all. I strongly suggest you to try again using the Xtk files from the repository.

Comment: Any messages in the console? Chrome F12 and Firefox Ctrl+Shift+K

Comment: Also click and drag downwards. I've noticed a problem with dicom files that the dicom reader will "flatten" the image in 3D space and put it on a plane instead of making a volume.

Answer (score 0):

Everything appears to work fine with the latest XTK Edge (https://github.com/xtk/X#readme). Could you point us to a non-working data set?

You might at some point see "white noise" instead of the actual image. It is most likely because the DICOM is JPEG compressed. XTK do not support that yet. To bypass it, you can uncompress the DICOM with dcmtk "dcmdjpeg" (http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/dcmdjpeg.html)

Thanks

Comment: The 'famous' Osirix datasets are stored using JPEG 2000. So you cannot use DCMTK, unless you buy the private modules.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I just had a look at 1 data-set, which appeared to be using a JPEG Lossless Transfer syntax.

Comment: The page referenced by OP states: "(All these DICOM files are encoded in JPEG2000 transfer syntax)". You need to redownload the DICOM files I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since Osirix Dataset is stored using JPEG 2000 Transfer Syntax, you are pretty much required to use gdcm:

```
$ gdcmconv --raw osirix_dataset.dcm output_raw.dcm
```

See the [gdcmconv man page](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmconv.html)

DCMTK/JPEG 2000 module is not free, see [here](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmjp2k.php.en).